# Message insert - adding external label

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm using gmail API to [insert](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/insert) an email to the inbox. When the `From` domain is outside the organization, I expect the external label to be added but it's not.

I'm using python and everything else is working, I am using a service account and able to impersonate on behalf the user's email and I'm using `labelIds` of `['INBOX', 'UNREAD']` and I need [the newly external label](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/04/external-label-gmail.html) as well but couldn't figure a way to add it through the API.

This feature is turned ON for the workspace.

Update - adding my code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'insert-messages-91e77b62878f.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert']


def validationService():
    # Set the credentials 
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.\
        from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes= SCOPES)
    # Delegate the credentials to the user you want to impersonate
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('<some_user>')
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    return service


def SendMessage(service, message):
    message = service.users().messages().insert(userId='me', body=message).execute() # me will use <some_user> from above
    return message


def CreateMessage(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['To'] = to
  message['From'] = sender
  message['Subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode(), 'labelIds': ['INBOX', 'UNREAD']}


def main():
    try:
        service = validationService()
        email = CreateMessage('some@external.com', "<some_user>", "Test", "This is a test")
        email_sent = SendMessage(service, email)
        print('Message Id:', email_sent['id'])
    except errors.HttpError as err:
        print('\n---------------You have the following error-------------')
        print(err)
        print('---------------You have the following error-------------\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - added.

Comment: Do you see the label appear if you use `send` instead of `insert`? My guess is that as this is a new label it may not be implemented fully yet for the API

Comment: @RafaGuillermo- with `send` API I cannot get it to send from an external domain, only from the impersonated user. About you comment that it's a new feature etc, can I expect to see it soon in the API somehow? For example, by a dedicated header or something like that? Is there a timeline?

Comment: AFAIK there's no timeline announced. If you open the inserted email to reply, do you see the regular 'External' banner at all? Or is there no hint of either anywhere?

Comment: I don't, also tried the reply since I understand that it should be shown there as well

Comment: I think it might be worth filing a feature request for this on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Thanks @RafaGuillermo - [created](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193427857).